# Storing Japanese characters in a table

Tags: sql-server, collation, unicode

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I want to store **Japanese characters** in one of the columns of my table.

Say I want to store Japanese names, how can I achieve that? Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `NCHAR(1 - 4000)` or `NVARCHAR`, either as `NVARCHAR(1 - 4000)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for storing anywhere from 4001 to just over 1,073,741,822 characters (or possibly less if storing any supplementary characters as described below).

Technically, you *can* store Japanese characters in `VARCHAR` fields if you use a `Japanese_*` Collation that is associated with Code Page 932. However, that is considered a "legacy" approach and would still leave you with some issues. The appropriate way to handle this is to use a Unicode datatype as mentioned above. Please see the **UPDATE** section at the end for details about `VARCHAR`.

You will also want to specify a Japanese collation so that the data compares and sorts as expected. You can find the available Japanese collations using:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_helpcollations() WHERE name LIKE N'Japanese%';
```

And you use that value in the field specification like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test
(
  JapaneseText NVARCHAR(3000) COLLATE Japanese_CI_AS_KS_WS
);
```

Please see the following section of MSDN pages for more info on using collation and what each of the `CI`/`CS`, `AS`/`AI`, `KS`, and `WS` mean, as well as `BIN`/`BIN2` and `SC` (not shown above): [Collation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848763.aspx).

And depending on which characters you need to store, you might need to pay close attention to the collations ending with `SC` (i.e. "Supplementary Characters"). By default, `NCHAR` / `NVARCHAR` data is stored as `UCS-2`, which is very similar to `UTF-16`, but `UCS-2` is always 2-bytes per character. On the other hand, `UTF-16`, in order to support more than 65,536 characters (max size of 2 bytes, or `UInt16.MaxValue` + 1) can store characters that are 4 bytes (known as "surrogate pairs"). Please see the following MSDN page on [Collation and Unicode Support ("Supplementary Characters" section)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx#Supplementary_Characters) for more details.

---

Absolutely do *not* use `NTEXT`. That has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005 came out! There is no benefit / reason for using it and, in fact, there are several drawbacks.

---

**UPDATE**

While not ideal, it is possible to store Japanese characters in `CHAR` / `VARCHAR` fields and variables. Doing so requires that the Database's default Collation be set to one that is associated with Code Page 932 (Shift-JIS). You can find that list of Collations by running the following query:

```sql
SELECT col.name
FROM   sys.fn_helpcollations() col
WHERE  COLLATIONPROPERTY(col.name, 'CodePage') = 932;
```

I did a simple test by creating a database with an entry from that list and ran the following statements:

```sql
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation'); -- Japanese_Unicode_CI_AS
SELECT COLLATIONPROPERTY(N'Japanese_Unicode_CI_AS', 'CodePage'); -- 932
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), 0x944094B294CD985198EE9AD79AA0); -- 如抜範浪偃壅國
SELECT LEN('如抜範浪偃壅國'), DATALENGTH('如抜範浪偃壅國'); -- 7, 14
```

This works because Code Page 932 is a Double-Byte Character Set (DBCS), which is different than UCS-2 / UTF-16 which is also double-byte. A DBCS character set is one that is double-byte within an 8-bit encoding (like the Extended ASCII Code Pages). You can see in that last query that the `DATALENGTH` is twice the the character `LEN`gth *and* that the data is in a `VARCHAR` type since there is no `N` prefix on the string literals and the `CONVERT` was to `VARCHAR`, not `NVARCHAR`. There are 4 DBCS Code Pages supported in Windows / SQL Server:

- 932 = Japanese (Shift-JIS)
- 936 = Chinese Simplified (GB2312)
- 949 = Korean
- 950 = Chinese Traditional (Big5)

Only use these if you absolutely need to, such as supporting interaction with a legacy system. Of course, the Collations are still fine to use, but store the data in `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score -3):

Just change the type of your attribute to TEXT instead of varchar:
[image]

Comment: That won't help: "Variable-length non-Unicode data in the code page of the server ..." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15